# Unable to fetch blob data in correct format using node/react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, blob

I have a node.js/react application. I am trying to fetch Binary data(any document of type jpeg/png/pdf) and then show it in a new browser tab. From react I am using fetch and from Node.js using axios.

The API request is successful and I am getting back BLOB data but I see the data of type text/html instead of "image/jpeg". Please see below for BLOB details in the console:

```
size: 277453
type: "text/html"
```

Now even if I try to change the type to jpeg by using the code below the new tab that opens up shows a corrupt file instead of the actual image.

```
previewDocument()
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    const blobWithType = res.slice(0, res.size, "image/jpeg");
    const urlToPreview = URL.createObjectURL(blobWithType);
    window.open(urlToPreview, "_blank").focus();
  })
```

I tried fetcing arrayBuffer as well via axios and convert the same to Blob but getting similar results. **If I do not set the type, I am seeing gibberish encoded data in the browser**

Comment: I had a little success with PDF documents now. The changes was content-type was application/json in node.js changing the document to text/html. Now I am getting correct document type from the BLOB. However, still facing issue with image. Even though the type of image is correct, it still does not show up correctly in browser(broken binary data). Happens to both png and jpeg type images.